# javascript format number

Tags: javascript, regex

Completely noob in regexs...

I want to format a number like: 1234123412341234 in something like:

12 3412 3412 3412 34

Currently I have the following code:

```
<label for="num1">Formmatted Number</label>
<input id="num1" type="text" name="num1" />

function space(str, after) {
    if (!str) {
        return false;
    }
    after = after || 4;
    var v = str.replace(/[^\dA-Z]/g, ''),
        reg = new RegExp(".{" + after + "}", "g");
    return v.replace(reg, function (a) {
        return a + ' ';
    });
}

var el = document.getElementById('num1');
el.addEventListener('keyup', function () {
    this.value = space(this.value, 4);
});
```

This formats the number as:

1234 1234 1234 1234

Can you please help me with this?

Comment: Will the number always be the same length?

Comment: What specifically are the rules for how you need this formatted?  Is it groups of 2, 4,4,4..., leftovers?  Or (leftovers),4,4,4...,2? Or something else?

Comment: In terms of lenght it should be always 16 like in the example. The format of the number should be always like: XX XXXX XXXX XXXX XX

Comment: What do you want to happen if the user inputs something other than 16 digits?

Comment: I'm replacing chars already... for now the length is not important... just the formatting :)

Comment: let's assume it will always input 16 as the field does not allow for more

Comment: If its always 16 chars and the format is fixed why not just `str = str.substring(0, 2) + " " + str.substring(2, 6) + " " + str.substring(6, 10) + " " ....`

Comment: The idea of using the regex is for the user to type each of the characters and do the formatting while typing. This way it would format only after typing everything.

Comment: So for each keyup it will enter a space automatically and the user would type plus 4 numbers and another space and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a neat way to progressively format the input. This even keeps the current cursor position in the correct location when inserting or deleting characters from the middle of the string:

```js
function count (str, re) {
  return str.split(re).length - 1
}

document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('input', function () {
  const { value, selectionStart } = this
  const oldIndex = selectionStart - count(value.slice(0, selectionStart), /\D/g)
  const numeric = value.replace(/\D/g, '')
  const sanitized = numeric
    .replace(/(\d{0,2})(\d{0,4})(\d{0,4})(\d{0,4})(\d{0,2}).*/, '$1 $2 $3 $4 $5')
    .trim()
  const newIndex = oldIndex + Math.floor((oldIndex + 2) / 4)

  this.value = sanitized
  this.setSelectionRange(newIndex, newIndex)
})
```

```html
<input type="text">
```

Comment: Thanks, this is indeed a nice solution!

Comment: It combines the replies of @MichałTurczyn

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that does not use regular expressions...

`const fmtNum = (num) => [2, 7, 12, 17].reduce((acc, curr) => [acc.slice(0, curr), " ", acc.slice(curr)].join(""), String(num));`

Take note that in order to accomplish this we must change the type from number to string.

This could be expanded to pass in an argument of different break indices where you specify where you want the spaces to be, like:

`const fmtNum = (num, spacePoints) => spacePoints.reduce((acc, curr) => [acc.slice(0, curr), " ", acc.slice(curr)].join(""), String(num));`

Invoking this would instead look like:
`fmtNum(1234123412341234, [2, 7, 12, 17])`

Comment: Thats a cool solution for the problem ... if it was to be performed after typing the full string :). In this case I need the string to be formatted correctly while the user is inputting the numbers... thats why I'm using keyup event :)

Comment: I believe my solution would still solve your problem if you invoked the function in the same place that you are invoking `space()` right now, in your event handler. It works on partial strings.

Answer (score 1):

You could replace with 2 starting digits and then add a space for all four digits.

```js
var number = 1234123412341234,
    string = number.toString().replace(/^..|..../g, '$& ');
    
console.log(string);
```

Or you could use a regular expression with positive lookahead for a special length to the end of the string.

```js
var number = 1234123412341234,
    string = number.toString().replace(/(?=(.{14}|.{10}|.{6}|.{2})$)/g, ' ');
    
console.log(string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just solved the problem :)... Thanks for your help anyway. As discussed in previous topics the length of 16 is not important as the field will only allow to insert 16 chars... otherwise that constraint could be included in the script.

```js
function format(str, after) {
    var v = str.replace(/[^\dA-Z]/g, ''),
        reg = new RegExp(".{" + after + "}", "g");
    return v.replace(reg, function (a) {
        if (a.length > 2) {
            a = a.substring(0,2) + ' ' + a.substring(2,a.length);
        }
        return a;
    });
}

var el = document.getElementById('num1');
el.addEventListener('keyup', function () {
    this.value = format(this.value, 4);
});
```

```html
<label for="num1">Formatted Number</label>
<input id="num1" type="text" name="num1" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern: `\b(\d{2})(\d{4})(\d{4})(\d{4})(\d{2})\b`, it will allow you to put particaler batches of your digits into separate group, then just replace it with `\1 \2 \3 \4 \5`, which will give you desired format.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ra1XEu/2)

Comment: Nice pattern for formatting a predefined string! thanks

Answer (score -1):

```
var el = document.getElementById('num1'); 
el.addEventListener('keyup', function () { this.value = format(this.value); }); 

function format(s){ 
    return  Array.prototype.map.call(s,(e,i)=>(e=e.replace(/\s/g,""), 
        (i+3)%5==0 ? " "+e:e)).join("");
}
```

If it's always 16 chars, then you can use map fn with condition If index is equal to 2 or index is the 4th character.